# Create table if it DOES NOT EXIST: JPA 2

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jpa

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892924/how-to-auto-create-database-schema-and-table-only-if-they-do-not-already-exist) thread (in the comment specially), I got to know that using

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" 
value="create"/>
```

instead of `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`

actually creates table according to @Entity class in my project. I am following that exact, but I am still getting the following error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'testdb.CUST_TABLE' doesn't exist

Following is my pom.xml for having look at versions of different dependencies I am using.

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Can anyone point out the problem or misunderstanding I am having?

**EDIT:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUST_TABLE")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long custId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false, length=50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", length=50)
    private String lastName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And my persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testjpa">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="nabin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="nabin" />
            <property name="hibernate.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: could you please share you hibernate cfg file and the annotated bean associated to CUST_TABLE table?

Comment: @MatteoN.By hibernate cfg file, you mean persistence.xml file? And annoted bean means my Entity Customer class?

Comment: yes, sorry. I mean the persistence.xml file and the bean that is intended to map the table that generates the error.

Comment: @MatteoN. Please see the edit

Comment: That persistence property is JPA 2.1. Are you using JPA 2.1 there? Hibernate 4.2?!

Comment: @NeilStockton Please have a look at my pom.xml mentioned in the question.

Comment: yes, and ? It says Hibernate 4.2 ... and is that JPA 2.1? It's a simple question. You must know what JPA you're using. And if not using JPA 2.1 then you can't use that property!

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry but how do I know which version of JPA I am using?

Comment: you shouldn't use both:
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
and
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>

I can't try it by myself at the moment, but I think that removing the second property (the one with value="create") should work.

Comment: @MatteoN. Yes. But I have tried it. Every combination possible. Using both, or using either of them. None worked. Lets see if Neil Stockton's suggestion works for me

Comment: Read the documentation for the VERSION of which JPA PROVIDER you are using!